trying to return gas price from within SC
I'm trying to read the current gas price (base fee) from within a smart contract.
After scanning online, there are purportedly two ways to do it, via tx.gasprice and block.baseFee. The former returns the gas cost of a transaction itself and so relies on the actual logic being executed at this time. The latter should return the base fee, but when I run it on Remix it returns 0 or says it estimates infinite gas.
Does anyone know whats going on? And/or how to effectively return the actual gas price from the chain?
function getBaseFee() public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 baseFee = block.basefee;
    return baseFee;
    // returns infinite gas
}

and
function getGasPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 gasPrice = tx.gasprice;
    return gasPrice;
    // returns 0
}


You've mentioned correctly that the value of tx.gasprice depends on the actual logic being executed in the corresponding transaction.
To get the block.basefee, you can store that in a storage variable to read and use its value in some other function, like:
uint256 public baseFee;

function getBaseFee() public {
    baseFee = block.basefee;
}

NOTE: On the forked and local networks, they just return the placeholder values i.e., 1 for block.basefee and 2 for tx.gasprice. So, to get the actual values you've to deploy the underlying contract on a real testnet/mainnet.
Also, if you return them from a view function on a real testnet, they just return 0, so you've to make the function as non-view function or state-changing / transactional function, in order to get the actual real-time values of these built-in global variables.
Moreover, as you can read from the comment of this post, tx.gasprice - block.basefee gives you the priority fee per gas for a particular transaction.
